# Pass link with params as parameter in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
  var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);            

  if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
  {
    return await ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First().AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl);
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

and url:
http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=portal&redirect_uri=http://192.168.8.11/ui/&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20iemk_portal&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3Djq3jXDl-8-axvCDDCvpvwaiqo48TjwQ9gj3bfcqlJafiKj-WB6hQci107FKclm5JZuAws_wEVXgbm1GD9E4EZXstbyS6yYNX8fdPpiaqaBTBrcwzhwIZAomHQSEK3mqAfwuZ15btCxgSVAIjwVVZQAaYEHnULg0ingm98IdamNwUU6Fl_cLBhkhpgGxn3odDTn4XnRa5qWyyhXdx28V3Qw&nonce=636420256366130000.ZjBiNWQ1NzgtMDA5NC00N2FjLWI1YjgtNDJkNzUwODZkZjIwNjI0M2Y0YmYtMWY1Mi00NjJhLTlmZDQtMjI1ZDc5OWNjM2Q

Method takes from url only: `/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=portal`.

What should be done to get `&redirect_uri=http://192.168.8.11/ui/` in param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that passing

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("http://192.168.8.11/ui/")
```

will work for you. Tested for asp net core